# The function r_2

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I would like express $r_2(n^2)$ where $r_2(n)$ is the number of representations of $n$ as sum of two squares.
For example :
$r_2(5) = 8$ since $ 5 = 4^2 + 1^2 = 1^2 + 4^2 = (-4)^2 + 1^2 = 1^2 + (-4)^2 = 4^2 + (-1)^2 = (-1)^2 + 4^2 = (-1)^2 + (-4)^2 = (-4)^2 + (-1)^2 $

There exists an explicit formula for $r_2(n)$ : $r_2(n) = 4(d_1(n) - d_3(n))$ where $d_1(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$ such as $d \equiv 1 [4]$ and $d_2(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$ such as $n \equiv 3 [4]$.

So  i will ask if it's possible to express $r_2(n^2)$ with $r_2(n)$

Thank you !

Comment: In your example, express $r_2(5^2)=12$ by $r_2(5)=8$. I don't see a pattern. Do you have the whole exercise? For what do you need to express $r_2(n^2)$ by $r_2(n)$?

Comment: I have to calculate this sum :  $$D(s) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{r_2(n^2)}{n^{2s}} $$ or at least to try to express this sum in term of special functions (zeta, dirichlet beta function, jacobi theta function, etc.)

Comment: See [Borwein](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwim8tTWwqf2AhWFt6QKHdwNBckQFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcarma.newcastle.edu.au%2Fresources%2Fjon%2FPreprints%2FPapers%2FBack%2520Burner%2520I%2FSalt%2Fborwein-sums1.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2s9q1x4-UoKWaBTjAtag58), etc.

Comment: thank you for this document !